# Selenium. How to get div id by href

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I have a some html code:

```
<div id = "NeedThis">
   <div style = "width:100%">
      <a href = "https://google.com/"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can i get a `NeedThis` by Selenium WebDriver FindElement and maybe XPath or CssSelector if i know a `href` in `<a>`? Language doesn't matter

Comment: Try `//div[./div/a[@href='https://google.com/']]` where you can substitute any URL (href).

Answer (score 1):

Use below:

```
String id= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[descendant::div/a[@href='https://google.com/']]")).getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(id);
```

**Output**:

```
NeedThis
```

Comment: imagine that I don't know how that id called

Comment: Then simply use : a[href*="https://google.com/"]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is how do I get an ID of a parent element. Your selector will return the `A`, not the parent element. And you've specified the ID (which is not known) as part of the selector.

Comment: Yes you're right @JeffC

Comment: @VladGromov : I've updated my answer to meet your requirement.

Comment: I removed the outdated part of your answer. To make your answer even better, explain how the XPath you provided works. How did you create it, etc.